# Git Azure deployment missing files from content directory (MVC4 project)

Tags: git, azure

I've been pushing from a local git repository to azure with no problems.

However, since adding some static content(a few png files) and pushing them to azure, I've noticed that they aren't getting pushed into the wwwroot directory on azure.

The files are being tracked by git and are landing in the git repo on the azure server. I was able to verify this by connecting by ftp and browsing folders.

However if I browse by ftp to the wwwroot directory, I can see that my new files have not been copied to this directory.

NOTE: I had two nice screenshots showing the files in one directory but not the other but I unfortunately can't post images on here as I'm a new user.

So to confirm:

- I've added a new file - test.png into /Content/images
- test.png is being tracked by git.
- test.png has reached the azure servers as I can see it when ftping to the /repository/ProjectName/Content/images directory
- test.png is not being copied into the wwwroot/Content/images directory, and is therefore not appearing on my azure website

The build action on these images is the same as other images which are appearing in the wwwroot directory (Content, Do not copy).

How can I get my new static resources to get copied into the wwwroot directory when pushing to azure?

Comment: As a quick check - could you do a local publish somewhere and verify that those images are copied to the correct place locally after the publish? Just to isolate where the problem is occurring

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just tried a local file system publish and all files appeared in the Content directory as expected. I'm going to modify an existing file and push that to azure to see if that gets updated

Comment: Ok I just touched the home page by putting a html comment into it and pushed to azure again. My content is now being copied to the wwwroot directory. I doubt that this was anything to do with the comment that I put into the homepage, but it may have triggered something with the deployment process on the azure end.

It would be lovely to know what happened.

Answer (score 12):

The most common reason for this issue is that the files in the Project and not correctly marked as Content, causing them not to be deployed. When that's the case, you'd see the same behavior when deploying via WebDeploy.

If you see this behavior and your files are correctly marked as Content, then I'd love to see a repro, ideally in the form of a github repo that I can try pushing myself to Azure.

Comment: I've just checked through the csproj file history and can see that all files were always set to "Content Include..."

Nothing changed with the inclusion of the static content files in terms of csproj file. I'll see if I can get a public repo setup that can be tested.

Comment: Thanks, would love to look at it.

Comment: Any updates on this? I am currently having the exact same issue.

Comment: I didn't get a repro to look at, so I was not able to investigate. If you have a consistent repro that you can share, please share the repo on Github (or wherever), and I can take a look.

Comment: I ran into this symptom today - the problem was that I had just added an htm file, saved the file, and then committed/pushed with git. What I neglected to do was "save all" which flushes csproj file changes to disk, so when I pushed, the `<Content>` entry for the new file wasn't in the csproj.

Comment: @AidanRyan yep, been there :)

Comment: this should be the answer, do we have someway to force an answer when the asker doesn't accept it?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have not accepted this answer as it did not solve my problems. I have indicated this in my first comment. There was something going else that a redeploy fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Build solution before commit to git to fix it.

Comment: Running a build locally forces a "Save All" in Visual Studio, which will fix this issue if you have added a new file and not pressed save all, so your project file changes were never saved. So yes, in some cases this will fix your problem, but would have also been fixed by running a save all.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where git was picking up the added images but when I deployed to the server the images were not getting through and I got an error

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable

or basically a **404 error**.

For me the issue was that the **project.csproj** file didn't had a reference to the images as a resource. So I edited my project.csproj in Notepad++ or you can do in any other editor and add the following under the ItemGroup –

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="Content\images\test.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Make sure that the you are using a **\ (backslash)** and not a  **/ (forward slash)**

PS: This might not be the best solution but works fine.